# Why run catkin_init_workspace inside src folder?

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't unstand why we run catkin_init_workspace inside the src folder, shoudn't it be the root folder, which is the catkin workspace folder?

```
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257405/why-run-catkin_init_workspace-inside-src-folder?/) by [sep_vanmarcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/29715/sep_vanmarcke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to run `catkin_init_workspace` yourself. `catkin_make` will take care of that for you automatically.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sep_vanmarcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/29715/sep_vanmarcke/) on 2017-03-20**:
Okay! I was always having to go back to tutorial because i was not sure (always happens when i don't know reason beyond stuff).

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-10-30**:
Are there any differences between one to the other? I've always wondered.